# How do I take in text from an author as a way to trigger certain responses when they've executed a command?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Let's say I made a command that a user uses to trigger a text message.

```
@client.command() 
async def hello(ctx) :
    await ctx.send (f'Hey there {ctx.author.name}! Say 1 to access the moderation module and 2 to access the fun module')
```

If they input 1, I would lead them to a series of actions that are different when they input 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a variable in the function that'll take a value.
*Breaking the below code:*

```
async def hello(ctx,input:int = None):
```

**input** is a variable.
**:int** is used to specify the value you want. It can be **:str** **:int** or blank.
*= None* is used to keep the value None till the user enters the value.

```
@client.command() 
async def hello(ctx,input:int = None):
    if input == None:
        await ctx.send (f'Hey there {ctx.author.name}! Say 1 to access the moderation module and 2 to access the fun module')
    elif input == 1:
        #ACCESS THE MODERATION MODULE
        pass
    elif input == 2:
        #ACCCESS THE FUN MODULE
        pass
```